# How to calcuate current IOPS consumed in AWS

Tags: sql-server, aws, storage

We have a SQL Server hosted on AWS using EC2 and EBS. SQL Files are hosted on EBS. EBS vol type is GP2 and drive IOPS is 480.

At an instance of time Write Througput in AWS is showing is 725 and Read Throughput is 72. Vol Queue Length is 0.5

So for that point of time, can we say?

1. Total IOPS consumed =  Write Througput + Read Throughput = 725 + 72 = 797
2. Since Total IOPS consumed(797) > Drive IOPS (480), can we say that IOPS are the bottleneck and IOPS needs to be increased?

If my understanding is wrong, then what is the way of identifying current IOPS value and how to determine if the current EBS volume is the bottleneck and needs to be upgraded?

Also just wanted to know, when Throughput comes into picture? how to identify if the bottleneck lies in Throughput and when it should be increased? How to calculate current throughput and max throughput?